# callback on several variables modification

Tags: rust

I have the variables `v1`, ..., `vn`, each one having a unique type `T1`, ..., `Tn`. I want to make it possible to subscribe to modifications
of these variables, not more then 4 at once.

```
use std::any::Any;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct T1(f32);
#[derive(Debug)]
struct T2(f32);

fn f1(a: &T1, b: &T2) {
    println!("you call f1: a {:?} b {:?}", a, b);
}

fn main() {
    let mut p1: Box<Any> = Box::new(T1(0.1));
    let mut p2: Box<Any> = Box::new(T2(0.1));

    let mut v = vec![p1, p2];

    let mut callbacks = ???    

    subscribe_on_change(&mut callbacks, T1_id, T2_id, f1);

    if let Some(num) = v[0].downcast_mut::<T1>() {
        println!("num: {:?}", num);
        *num = T1(5.1);
        callbacks.update(T1_id);
    }
}
```

How can I implement such functionality using only the stable or beta compiler?

Because `std::any::Any::get_type_id` is only usable in the nightly compiler, I can extend `Any` with my trait, and replace `TypeId` with my own `enum`, if there is no more elegant solution.

But what would I put into `callbacks`, if I want call functions
with signatures: `(&Tk1)`, `(&Tk1, &Tk2)`, `(&Tk1, &Tk2, &Tk3)`,
`(&Tk1, &Tk2, &Tk3, &Tk4)`, where I have at least 10 types,
so because of each ki != kj, I have 10 + 10 * 9 + 10 * 9 * 8 + 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 variants.

Because it is not clear, I want to call the callbacks if any of the arguments are updated. For example, in the code above, `f1` should be called if variables of type `T1` or `T2` were updated. I have `n` unique variables, each of them having a unique type and I put then into a `Vec<Box<Any>>`.

Comment: I don't understand the task... In what exact circumstances would the callback be triggered? Perhaps simplifying the problem to less variables would help.

Comment: @E_net4 if callback subscribed to update of `v1` and `v2` then it should be called on update of `v1` or `v2`.